# & character in product name causing validation errors

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I have a page that generates a list of my products from a database. It then outputs the name, however many of the names have & in them. w3c validator is telling me:

Line 157, Column 66: character "&" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data

and that I should be using `&amp;` instead.

Is there something I can do? Do I need to change all & in the database to "&"?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, try changing `&` to `&amp;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is output content from a database, you should be wrapping those variables in [`htmlentites()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before writing them to HTML.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($productname);
```

The ampersand `&` must be written as the entity `&amp;`.  There are a number of other similar entities or special characters which you need to be prepared for, and the functions mentioned above handle them.

Additionally, and more importantly than W3C validation, `htmlspecialchars()` will offer protection against cross-site scripting attacks, if you have any user generated content (like user reviews, etc).

```
$product = "Eggs & Bacon";
echo htmlspecialchars($product);
// Eggs &amp; Bacon
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the & to `&amp;` - i.e. escape it for HTML

**Update**

You should also consider other characters e.g. <, >, ", ...

Look up the specification on those characters - google it!

Comment: -1 Changing these characters one by one is not the best way to do this when there are native PHP functions to do it for you.

Comment: @liquorvicar - Nowhere in the OP does it say that PHP is being used.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass all your data through the [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before you echo it into the web page.

`&` is a special character in HTML, so it should be `&amp;` if you want a literal ampersand. `htmlspecialchars()` will escape all the special characters in a string, so it can safely be displayed on a web page.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to represent a & in XML is using the entity `&amp;`. You don't necessarily need to replace them in the database, but you'll need to replace them somewhere before representing the data as XML or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change it in the database. Change it when you retrieve it, immediately before output. Changing it in the database commits you to assuming you're targeting an HTML output environment. If you target something else, like producing a PDF or other file, now you you have to UNDO that `&` -> `&amp;` conversion.

Always store the data in its basic "raw" format, and convert as needed for the target environment.

Comment: I would disagree - the sentiment is good but you may wish to consider the performance implications if you are usually delivering HTML

Comment: I would vote you up as this is an important point but you haven't actually told him how to convert the characters for HTML output.

Comment: @liquorvicar - To be fair (s)he has not specified the language (s)he is using. Could be C++, Perl, PHP, Some shell script, ...

Comment: @EdHeal But the OP did tag the question as PHP so would it no be fair to assume that's the language? And as regards performance, if it's a problem you might look at caching the database results outside of the database rather than storing the HTML representation in the DB (although I guess you might consider storing it in the database).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are just getting a list from a database and then looping through this to output to a page.   If so what you can do is when you get the field back from the database, do a replace string on that field to replace the & with the html name for that special character  & amp; (without the space)

in php it should be something along the lines of str_replace("&","& amp;")  check out the php pages at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

for all the different parameters and usages.